# Refactoring dropdown list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a dropdown list component

```
const NudgeTrigger = ({ isShowItem, checkItem, index, title }) => {
  const [toggleArrow, setToggleArrow] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div className={`nudgeTrigger ${toggleArrow ? 'nudgeTriggerUpArrow' : ''}`} onClick={() => {
      // Does the index exist in the showListItem array? Yes: delete it and close dropdown. No: add it and open dropdown.
      isShowItem(index) ? checkItem(index, false) : checkItem(index, true)
      setToggleArrow(!toggleArrow)
    }}>
      <p key={index} className={styles.nudgeTitle}>{title}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It is used in the following context

```
<NudgeTrigger isShowItem={isShowItem} checkItem={checkItem} index={index} title={nudge.title}/>
```

where `NudgeTrigger` is mapped over an array of values and receives an `index`

I want the third item of the array to have a separate state for toggling its arrow image and added a `third` prop to `NudgeTrigger`

```
const NudgeTrigger = ({ isShowItem, checkItem, index, title, third }) => {
  const [toggleArrow, setToggleArrow] = useState(false)
  const [toggleThirdArrow, setToggleThirdArrow] = useState(third)
  {toggleThirdArrow ? (
      <>
        <div className={`nudgeTrigger ${toggleArrow ? 'nudgeTriggerUpArrow' : ''}`} onClick={() => {
          // Does the index exist in the showListItem array? Yes: delete it and close dropdown. No: add it and open dropdown.
          isShowItem(index) ? checkItem(index, false) : checkItem(index, true)
          setToggleArrow(!toggleArrow)
        }}>
          <p key={index} className={styles.nudgeTitle}>{title}</p>
        </div>
      </>  
    ) : (
      <>
        <div className={`nudgeTrigger ${toggleThirdArrow ? 'nudgeTriggerUpArrow' : ''}`} onClick={() => {
          // Does the index exist in the showListItem array? Yes: delete it and close dropdown. No: add it and open dropdown.
          isShowItem(index) ? checkItem(index, false) : checkItem(index, true)
          setToggleThirdArrow(!toggleThirdArrow)
        }}>
          <p key={index} className={styles.nudgeTitle}>{title}</p>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

which is used in the following context

```
<NudgeTrigger isShowItem={isShowItem} checkItem={checkItem} index={index} title={nudge.title} third={index === 2}/>
```

However I receive 2 errors. Hovering over `NudgeTrigger` on VSCode the error states

```
'NudgeTrigger' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element
```

And actually rendering the page causes the second error

```
Error: NudgeTrigger(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `return` in `NudgeTrigger`

Try below code for component:-

```
  const NudgeTrigger = ({ isShowItem, checkItem, index, title, third }) => {
    const [toggleArrow, setToggleArrow] = useState(false);
    const [toggleThirdArrow, setToggleThirdArrow] = useState(third);
    return (
      <>
        {toggleThirdArrow ? (
          <>
            <div
              className={`nudgeTrigger ${
                toggleArrow ? 'nudgeTriggerUpArrow' : ''
              }`}
              onClick={() => {
                // Does the index exist in the showListItem array? Yes: delete it and close dropdown. No: add it and open dropdown.
                isShowItem(index)
                  ? checkItem(index, false)
                  : checkItem(index, true);
                setToggleArrow(!toggleArrow);
              }}
            >
              <p key={index} className={styles.nudgeTitle}>
                {title}
              </p>
            </div>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <div
              className={`nudgeTrigger ${
                toggleThirdArrow ? 'nudgeTriggerUpArrow' : ''
              }`}
              onClick={() => {
                // Does the index exist in the showListItem array? Yes: delete it and close dropdown. No: add it and open dropdown.
                isShowItem(index)
                  ? checkItem(index, false)
                  : checkItem(index, true);
                setToggleThirdArrow(!toggleThirdArrow);
              }}
            >
              <p key={index} className={styles.nudgeTitle}>
                {title}
              </p>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
```